# Blender 2.91.2: Rendering looks pixelated in Blender's image view (rendering is not pixelated!)

Tags: rendering, image

The rendered image, in Blender, looks very pixelated.
But, when I save the image and open it paint.net, the image is as clear as it gets.
You can see that in the following images. Best image is the third one. All images are at the same zoom level as in Blender (1:1).

Any ideas, hints and "duh"s are appreciated.

This is in Blender:
[image: Rendered image in Blender, image view.]

Same image stored and opened in paint.net:
[image: Same image stored and opened in paint.net]

Side by side:
[image: Left image, sharp as it gets viewed in paint.net. Right: Pixelated image in Blender image view.]
Left image, sharp as it gets viewed in paint.net. Right: Pixelated image in Blender image view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day, the problem went away. Maybe a reboot was required?! Anyways, the problem is gone and I don't know what it was.